# cin truncates multi-word string input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to show every letter that I wrote on the screen. However, it doesn't seem to recognize spaces. When there's a space, the program just seems to terminate itself. For example, if I wrote "This is cpp", it just prints "This"

I tried using:

```
if (MessagetEnc[i] == static_cast<char>(32))
    {
        cout << static_cast<char>(MessagetEnc[i]);
    }
```

to specifically show that I want the compiler to treat space as a character instead of just "white space" but that didn't work.

The code of the area I think is causing problems is below. I don't think you'll need the other part because it's just collecting the user's input.

```
int n = MessagetEnc.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    
   if (MessagetEnc[i] == ('a' |'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm'))
    {
    cout << static_cast<char>(MessagetEnc[i] + EncCode);
    }

}
```

I don't think anything is wrong with the compiler, it's probably the way cout works or something, I don't know.

Just in case you need the other part:

```
int EncCode; 
cout << "Encryption code: " << endl;
cin >> EncCode; 

string MessagetEnc;
cout << "Message to Encrypt:";
cin >> MessagetEnc;
 cout <<"Encrypted message:";
```

Comment: `MessagetEnc[i] == ('a' |'b'...` doesn't do what you think it does. You need `MessagetEnc[i] == 'a' || MessagetEnc[i] == 'b' || ...`. There are better ways to achieve the same result but you need to understand this one first.

Comment: First off `|` is a binary operation, `||` is or

Comment: `cin >> MessagetEnc;` What does `MessagetEnc` contain after this line?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I tried using it but it gave me a warning that I should use the bitwise operator '|'

Comment: And `static_cast<char>(32)` doesn't make any sense whatsoever. Don't use magic numbers. If you need a specific character, type it between single quotes.

Comment: "it gave me a warning" You need to ask a question about the warning, rather than try and apply random perturbations to the code.

Comment: @Woodford  int n = MessagetEnc.size();

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
string MessagetEnc;
...
cin >> MessagetEnc;
```

See the section `cin and strings` on the page http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

> However, cin extraction always considers spaces (whitespaces, tabs, new-line...) as terminating the value being extracted, and thus extracting a string means to always extract a single word, not a phrase or an entire sentence.

> To get an entire line from cin, there exists a function, called getline, that takes the stream (cin) as first argument, and the string variable as second.

Answer (score 0):

`>>` gets chars until it hits whitespace (space, enter, stuff like that). If you want to read a whole line, use `getline()`, defined in the header `<string>`. More info here on getline: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/. More info here on the `>>` operator: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/.

Example:

```
int EncCode; 
cout << "Encryption code: " << endl;
cin >> EncCode; 

string MessagetEnc;
cout << "Message to Encrypt:";
getline(cin,MessagetEnc); //gets until enter
 cout <<"Encrypted message:";
```

Be sure to `#include <string>`.

**How to use `getline()`:**

First parameter: an `istream`, like `cin`.

Second parameter: a `string` to put the result into.

Third parameter (optional): a `char` to stop reading input at, by default `'\n'`. (enter/newline)